# What's tap off mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm reading a book "pretty pretty boys" from Gregory Ashe. There is a word I can't understand "tap off". I give you the context :"The rest of the day had passed in a blur of work: tapping off the garage door, examining the property for any physical evidence ...". Is this maybe a word from the vocabularies's police. The book is a novel crime.
Thanks

Comment: The book is a "crime novel", not a "novel crime".  A "novel crime" means a new type of crime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the preview on Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=p6LNDwAAQBAJ&q=off+the+garage+door#v=snippet&q=a%20blur%20of%20work&f=false), the word there is **taping** (from the verb *to tape*), not *tapping* (from the verb *to tap*); if your edition spells it "tapping," it's probably a misprint of some sort.

[TFD defines](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tape+off) to *tape off* as:

> To restrict or reserve some location or area by encircling it with tape: *The police taped off the crime scene.*

In context, the implication is presumably that they were putting some sort of caution tape (like [the yellow tape in this photo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/Airmen_team_up_to_build_shelter_120413-F-UP124-080.jpg)) in front of the garage door to warn others not to enter and disturb the crime scene.